# Why SQL Server Login does not map to any user, but still could operate all actions?

Tags: sql-server

Have a SQL Server instance on my local machine. I use window authentication to login the instance. My understanding is a login needs to map to a user, and that user needs assign some certain database level roles, then can operate some sort of actions.

But interesting, I did not assign any user to map this login, nor attach any database level role to any user. This login could still run all of the actions on that database. Can someone explain why is that?

Thanks

Comment: Is the login a member of the `sysadmin` fixed server role?  A sysadmin can connect to any database as `dbo`.

Comment: I see. Yes, the login is a member of the sysadmin server role. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: Was otherwise going to suggest that the user belongs to an AD Group, that has permissions in the database.

Comment: Members of the sysadmin role are automatically maped to the DBO role. DBO members are not mapped by default to the Sysadmin role.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That login acts or as `SYSADMIN` or as `Guest` user in the database